# Fix textview at the top and button at the bottom of LinearyLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In a linearLayout, I want to fix textView at the top and button at the bottom of linearyLayout and rest of the layout to be filled with empty space (the middle layout). With layout_weight=0 for textView, button and a dummy layout_weight=1 for dummy textView, I was hoping that the dummyView would occupy middle layout (due to more weightage) in the layout. But what I get is only the first textView displayed. Any pointers?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dummy_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/complete_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/done_button"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change height of button & textviewsto `0dp` and use `layout_weight` as needed

Comment: `RelativeLayout` would be a better option

Answer (score 3):

Use `RelativeLayout`
Add `alignparentTop` to first textView
Add `alignparentBottom` to the button

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout from `horizontal` to `vertical`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="**vertical**" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dummy_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/complete_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/done_button"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be horizontal? Why vertical?

Comment: if you want the text view at the top and button at the bottom then it should be vertical. vertical ( | ) horizontal ( - )

Comment: Its still the same, had to use RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Use android:gravity= "top" for textView
and android:gravity = "bottom" for button

Comment: I tried the option, but didnt work. Had to use RelativeLayout

Comment: Use relative layout and for text use alignParentTop = " true", for button use alignParentBottom = "true"